# Euclidean distance calculations in R not making sense

Tags: r

(Preface: I'm neither a statistician nor a programmer. I work in the humanities, so have mercy on my soul).

I need to calculate the Euclidean distance between a series of points in R. I've been using dist(), as follows:

```
> x <- c(0,0)
> y <- c(0,10)
> dist(rbind(x,y))
   x
y 10
```

So far, so good. But when I was looking at my results (with real numbers), they were horribly off. So much so that I figured my R script was grabbing data from the wrong columns. But I checked, and it isn't.

So I started playing around with toy numbers, and I was in for a surprise. The above example (a vertical line) works correctly, as does the following (a horizontal line):

```
> x <- c(0,10)
> y <- c(0,0)
> dist(rbind(x,y))
   x
y 10
```

But when the line the two points form is diagonal, strangeness ensues:

```
> x <- c(0,10)
> y <- c(0,10)
> dist(rbind(x,y))
  x
y 0
```

A distance of 0? Huh? That can't be right.

And when the points are identical (that's quite possible in my data), we go down the rabbit hole:

```
> x <- c(0,0)
> y <- c(10,10)
> dist(rbind(x,y))
     x
y 14.14214
```

Should this not be 0? The points are identical, after all, so there can be no distance between them.

Just in case there's something wrong with dist(), I tried to implement the formula manually, going by Wikipedia. Same results:

```
> sqrt(sum((x - y) ^ 2))
[1] 14.14214
```

As I said above, my math background is minimal, so I fully expect that the error here is mine. If so, please explain what it is and how to correct it. But from where I stand right now, it seems like something is very wrong.

And worst of all, I can't analyze my data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you want `dist(cbind(x, y))`, not `dist(rbind(x, y))`.

Comment: That does indeed seem to do the trick -- since my x vector has all x coordinates, and my y vector has all y ones, I need to bind by column, not row. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

`dist` computes a distance matrix between **each pair of rows** of its argument. If your rows are identical, as in your first 'strange' example, then the distance will indeed be 0. If your rows are constant 0 and constant 10, as in your second example, then the distance will indeed be sqrt((10-0)^2+(10-0)^2) = 14.142...

Answer (score 7):

What you think you're doing when you run this:

```
x <- c(0,10)
y <- c(0,0)
dist(rbind(x,y))
```

is that you've defined two points, `(0,0)` and `(10,0)`, and asked R to calculate the distance between those two points.

But you haven't, in fact, asked R to do that at all!

When you `rbind` the vectors `x` and `y` together, you end up with the matrix:

```
rbind(c(0,10),c(0,0))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0   10
[2,]    0    0
```

When you call `dist`, it calculated the distance between the **rows** of this matrix. Hence, the distance between them is 10.

Hopefully that makes sense now!

Comment: Thanks very much! It does indeed make sense now.